# spring data elasticsearch dynamic shards, replicas

Tags: java, spring

```
@Document(indexName = "#{indexName.getBanIndexName()}",
        shards = 3,
        replicas = 2,
        refreshInterval = "-1")
```

.

```
package org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import org.elasticsearch.index.VersionType;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Persistent;

@Persistent
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
public @interface Document {

    String indexName();

    String type() default "";

    boolean useServerConfiguration() default false;

    short shards() default 5;

    short replicas() default 1;

    String refreshInterval() default "1s";

    String indexStoreType() default "fs";

    boolean createIndex() default true;

    VersionType versionType() default VersionType.EXTERNAL;
}
```

I want to dynamically inject shards and replicas per deployment environment using @annotation.

Is there a way to dynamically inject values ​​into the shards field of short type belonging to @annotation?

Comment: No, the values need to be resolved at compile time. If you need this to be configurable, maybe have to move it in class configuration

Answer (score 0):

You should use `useServerConfiguration=true`  to control index creation based on deployment environment.
You can also invoke

```
PUT _index_template/template_1
{
  "index_patterns": ["YOUR_INDEX_PATTERN"],
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 3
    }
}
```

before spinning up your repository